# New topbar clashes with SciFi.SE

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

Our header isn't a solid color, so the solid topbar looks horrible.

Proposal:  Instead of a background-color of #212121, give it some alpha transparency:

```
background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, .4);
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Semi-Transparent Topbar]

<sub>(I'm using Greasemonkey to put Meta and Chat back in the topbar, that's why I have the links)</sub>

Comment: It's a good look, I'll give you that. Makes the reputation text a bit hard to read though.

Comment: This looks *so much better!* See how the black bar looks over at [Christianity SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/). Ugh! This would be awesome there as well!

Comment: I suggested this [on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210119/144439).

Comment: [This Meta.SO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar) has some userscripts and userCSS that lets you customize the topbar to your liking.

Comment: @Keen I've been making my own as I come across something I don't like  ;)

Answer (score 6):

I have pushed a change to make the topbar now translucent. the CSS I used is rgba(0,0,0,0.8). This way it will play nicer with our sites that are visually heavy.

Comment: 8 is not enough.

Comment: @KyleJones I've made it more translucent.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks better now.